# Which one is best to implement either Fluro or Default Navigator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm beginner in Flutter, I just go through some of the docs and got that there are many ways to navigate from one screen to another **ex. Fluro and default Navigator** , but I confused which would be better to implement in my very first flutter project?
Can anyone explain in detail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Default Navigator:`**
This is the `built-in` routing system provided by Flutter. It's simple to use and suitable for most applications, especially smaller ones or those with less complex navigation needs. It offers the `MaterialPageRoute` and `CupertinoPageRoute` classes for navigating between screens, managing routes, and passing arguments.

**`Fluro:`** Fluro is a third-party routing package for Flutter that offers more customization and flexibility than the default Navigator. It allows you to define routes using a different approach and provides `more control over transitions`, `route parameters`, and `deep linking`. It's beneficial for larger applications with more complex routing requirements or when you need fine-grained control over routing behavior.

**The choice between them depends on your app's specific needs:**

- For simpler apps with straightforward navigation requirements, the default Navigator might suffice and be easier to implement.
- For larger applications or those needing more customized transitions, deep linking, or dynamic route management, Fluro could be more suitable due to its advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out these tutorials from Flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#navigation

Personally, I've always used `Navigator` and that's what I would suggest you start with, as you don't need to install any package to use it. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) you can find the documentation about it.

Comment: Sure GBerga, I'll check it, Thank you for your quick response.